# Return the factors of a partially-factored polynomial, without factoring

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, factorization

Suppose I have an integer polynomial `f` that is in a factored form, say `f = (1 + x) * (2 + x + x^3) * (2 + x^5)`. I want a function similar to `FactorList` that accepts `f` and returns `{ 1 + x, 2 + x + x^3, 2 + x^5 }`.

Normally I would just use `FactorList`. However, I am worried `FactorList` will attempt to further factor the factors, which might become a time sink as I work with polynomials whose factors are very high in degree and have many terms. I do NOT need the function to further factor.

Outside of string conversion and manipulation, I don't know what functions can achieve this easily. I would guess, however, that this is easily achievable, without the use of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ClearAll[factorlist]
factorlist[exp_Times] := List @@ exp
factorlist[exp_Power] := {First@exp}
```

Here are a few examples:

```
f = (1 + x)*(2 + x + x^3)*(2 + x^5)
g = 2 (x^2 + 1)
h = (2 x + 1)^3

factorlist /@ {f, g, h}

(* Out:
{
 {1 + x, 2 + x + x^3, 2 + x^5}, 
 {2, 1 + x^2}, 
 {1 + 2 x}
}
*)
```